# unobtrusive Validation not working for Textarea in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, client-side, unobtrusive-validation

I am facing an issue regarding the client side validation using unobtrusive Validation plugin in MVC 4. The validation works fine with **TextBoxFor** but it is not working with **TextAreaFor**. I have tried using **EditorFor** instead but not getting validation appear in the tooltip ( As given in the image ).

**Model**

```
[Required]
    [Display(Name = "New Message")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string txtMessage { get; set; }
```

**Bundle Config**

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveBoardTaskMessage", "Task", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "BoardTaskMessageForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){

        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.txtMessage, new { @cols = 40, @rows = 6, @style = "font-family: inherit;resize: none;width:404px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.txtMessage)
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `TextAreaFor` with `EditorFor`. Since your model already has the multiline flag set, this should not impact your UI, but it should work around a potential (and past documented for some versions) bug with `TextAreaFor`.